# Can you identify this hero? Has a cape and a sword

Tags: character-identification

Can you identify this hero? Has a cape and a sword.

I only have this terrible-quality picture from [Secret Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Service_(magazine)), a computer games magazine, from 1993, and would like to know what hero it is.

https://archive.org/details/secretservicemagazine-1993-01/page/n21/mode/1up

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason to expect this is a science fictional or fantastical character rather than just a warrior or some such?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It looks pretty fantasy-esque. I'm minded to give it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Looks fantasy to me but you might be right and perhaps it's just a warrior.

Comment: Here’s the same image in color on a kids collectible: https://colnect.com/en/kids_meal_toys/kids_meal_toy/12885-Capeman-Rondos-FlipposPogsTazos-Belgium

Comment: @Spc_555 Thanks! I used Tineye and Images.google.com on your image and got this: https://i.imgur.com/LiSexPp.jpg

Comment: @Spc_555 - Those pogs appear to have crudely copied (and presumably unlicensed) characters from a range of sources including Ming the Merciless; https://www.milkcapmania.co.uk/386-Rondos.html

Comment: @Tom, I used to own this magazine as a kid. I always assumed it was [Thorgal Aegirsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorgal).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the original picture! It's a clipart from Corel Draw 3 called "Capeman.tif".

[image]

All images from the "LIBRARY\PHTPAINT\FANTASY" folder:

[image]

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: @Valorum I checked on Wikipedia what DTP and DTP-alike programs were popular in 1993 and then I downloaded them from sites like archive.org. I checked: Aldus PageMaker 5, QuarkXPress 3, Ventura Publisher 3, Micrografx Picture Publisher 3 and CorelDRAW 3. I also downloaded ClickArt CDs. And I just checked all of the files. I found the Capeman in LIBRARY\PHTPAINT\FANTASY with a few other fantasy characters.

Comment: CorelDraw 3 was released on 15 May 1992; I'm guessing the magazine used the image (modified) for its May '93 release.

Answer (score 35):

This image is used by *Secret Service Magazine* ([May, 1993](https://archive.org/details/secretservicemagazine-1993-05/page/n11/mode/thumb)) to illustrate the 'barbarian' character from the Amiga game [*Times of Lore*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_of_Lore). It's not clear whether this was an original illustration by the makers of the magazine or culled from elsewhere.

You may wish to note that this image *has* appeared elsewhere in this form, for example on these (copyright infringing) [Rondo milk caps](https://www.milkcapmania.co.uk/386-Rondos.html) where he's described as "*Capeman*".

[image]

Comment: OK, I got it. Secret Service 5/93

Comment: @Tom - [Secret Service Magazine - May 1993](https://archive.org/details/secretservicemagazine-1993-05/page/n11/mode/thumb) page 7

Comment: Actually, I don't think this image ever appeared in the Times of Lore ads, manual, game box, etc.  I think it was an image from somewhere else that *Secret Service* slapped in place near descriptions of fantasy games).

Comment: @Buzz You might be right. He kinds looks like Conan the Barbarian (2 golden bracelets on both hands just like Conan.)

Comment: @Tom It is definitely reminiscent of Frazetta's famous cover for *Conan the Adventurer*.

Comment: @Tom I think you should remove the accepted answer checkmark here, there’s no evidence this image has anything to do with the Times of Lore game

Comment: @Spc_555 - The only place I've found it is next to the Time of Lore game. Can you give another example where it's used elsewhere?

Comment: @Valorum Spc_555 found this image on a Belgian collectible https://i.imgur.com/LiSexPp.jpg

Comment: @Tom - That picture appears to be a fan-creation based on the picture above.

Comment: @Valorum yes, please see my comment to the question. Seems like this was a widely available image in the 90s and this magazine just used it to illustrate games. Also I’ve looked through all Times of Lore manuals/packaging/marketing materials I could find on the Internet and this image is nowhere to be seen. Also it seems that the original version is indeed with a cape, you can find a lot of “caped” copies being used as avatars etc and none without a cape.

Comment: @Spc_555 - Hmm. Is it more likely that this is the original (noting that it's much higher quality) and someone crudely added batman's cape or that this is a copy and that someone painstakingly *removed* the cape?

Comment: @Spc_555 - I've been through about twenty issues of Secret Service and can't find any other uses of the picture. Additionally, **all of the pictures used in the magazine appear to relate directly to the game being shown**, with no common illustrations for game type (e.g. Barbarian doesn't have this same picture, nor does Doman, although both are 'barbarian versus baddies' type games)

Comment: @Valorum I think you should agree that the caped version I found ( https://colnect.com/en/kids_meal_toys/kids_meal_toy/12885-Capeman-Rondos-FlipposPogsTazos-Belgium ) is the same as in the original question, but in color. Which means the magazine got it somewhere (with a cape!) and removed colors.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the edit, upvoted your answer

Comment: @Spc_555 - I think it's far more likely that photocopied the original, added a cape (by photocopying one image on top of the other) and then colourised it, hence the shitty image quality in the repro. I should stress that that's absolutely Batman's cape.

Comment: @Valorum actually yes I believe it’s Conan with Batman’s cape. But there are so many Conan imagery that finding the source is really difficult

Comment: @Spc_555 - I think it might be original to the magazine. Almost all of their artwork seems to have been hand-drawn or copied from box-art.

Comment: @Valorum I just found out Conan did have cape! https://comicvine.gamespot.com/conn/4005-31148/

Answer (score 4):

The original image has been already found and the resemblance with Conan has already been mentioned in the comments. Also it has been stated that it's pretty difficult to find the "inspiration" for the clipart but it doesn't look like Frazetta inspired to me but taken from the great John Buscema.

Following it's an image from Conan by Buscema with a similar outfit and pose.
According to this [site](https://comics.ha.com/itm/original-comic-art/splash-pages/john-buscema-the-savage-sword-of-conan-222-splash-page-1-original-art-marvel-1994-/a/7242-95055.s), it's taken from [Savage Sword of Conan Vol 1 222](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Savage_Sword_of_Conan_Vol_1_222) (June, 1994)

[image: Conan by John Buscema]

Comment: Very similar indeed!

Comment: What's the date on this illustration? It is highly likely that one was directly inspired by the other.

Comment: @TylerH It seems that it was published in june 1994 but Conan and Buscema have got a long previous relation.

Comment: This image isn't head on like the one in the question. They may have a similar origin but they're different.